# Display only the individual error message using validation Engine

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

Iam using jQuery Validation engine in my Asp.net MVC application. I would like to show  individual error messages.Now it showing both the individual error message and also summary at the bottom. So it would be really helpful to know how can I display only the individual error messages rather than both .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my popup script where fancybox is loaded ie

```
               $("a.create-report").fancybox(
    {
        'autoDimensions':true,
        'centerOnScroll':true,
        'padding'        :'20px'
    });                      

    just added

$('#fancybox-close').click(function () {
        $(".formError").remove();
    });

    $('#fancybox-overlay').live("click",function () {
        $(".formError").remove();
    });
```

Then the validation summary get removed